# Derivatives of Integrals: Deriving Components of Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I am trying to derive the values in the following proof from *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*, by Walter A. Strauss:

[image]
[image]

Theorem 1 is as follows:

[image]

---

**My derivations are as follows:**

$$\dfrac{d}{dt} I(t) = \dfrac{ \partial{g} }{ \partial{t} } (t, a(t), b(t)) = \dfrac{ \partial{g} }{ \partial{t} } + \dfrac{ \partial{g} }{ \partial{a} } \dfrac{ da }{ dt } + \dfrac{ \partial{g} }{ \partial{b} } \dfrac{ db }{ dt }$$

$$\dfrac{ \partial{g} }{ \partial{t} } = \dfrac{d}{dt} \int^b_a f(x, t) \ dx = \int^b_a \dfrac{ \partial{f} }{ \partial{t} }(x, t) $$

$$\dfrac{ db }{ dt } = b'(t)$$

$$\dfrac{ da }{ dt } = a'(t)$$

Now, here is the part that I am worried about.

I recognised that I need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The following is from *Thomas's Calculus*, 14th Edition:

[image]

So we have

$$ \dfrac{ \partial{g} }{ \partial{b} } = \dfrac{ d }{ db } \int^b_a f(x, t) \ dx = f(b, t)$$

What I did with this equation is I assumed that, in reference to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $x = b(t)$. Is this correct?
Also, I'm unsure if $\dfrac{ d }{ db }$ in $ \dfrac{ d }{ db } \int^b_a f(x, t) \ dx $ is correct or whether it should be $ \dfrac{ \partial }{ \partial{b} } $?

I ask because, in the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the function being integrated is a function of $t$ -- not $x$. But the upper limit of integration is $x$. In our case, the upper limit of integration $b$ is a function of $t$. So I'm confused as to how we apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here?

We also have

$$ \dfrac{ \partial{g} }{ \partial{a}} = \dfrac{ d }{ da } \left[ - \int^a_b f(x, t) \ dx \right] = - f(a, t)$$

I did the same with this equation, except I used the properties of integrals to flip the limits of integration, so that we have $x = a(t)$, in order to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. As with the former equation, I'm wondering if this correct?

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to check my derivations and address my mentioned concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from the commonly used abuse of notation in calculus namely the abusive usage of free and bound variables.

Here we are dealing with operations acting on functions. Strictly speaking functions are things that take objects and output obects. In formal theory such as ZF, they can be defined as sets of ordered pairs for which there are no two pairs that are equal on their first element but differ on the second.

It's common to specify a function by its value on an arbitrary element of it's domain like $ x \mapsto x^2 $. Here x is a bound variable it has no independent meaning by itself it just acts as a dummy to specify any object in the domain. Now since that's often too verbose for the purposes of computation usually the $\mapsto$ is skipped and the function's are specified like $x^2$ which is now ambiguous since $x$ is now a free variable and could be just some number, but that's ok since people usually understand what's intended by such notation (namely that this variable is actually bound and not free).

The derivatives follow similar convention. $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is understood as the function $x \mapsto \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x) }{h}$.

However this slight abuse goes even further beyond. Namely nonsensical expressions such as $\frac{df}{dx}$ are used, where now we have two free variables that have no connection whatsoever and it requires full knowledge of the context to understand what the author of such nonsense has intended. What's even more confusing can be the use of the same symbols as both functions and numbers in different contexts, with nonsense like $x=x(y)$, $y=y(x)$, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ where we might've used $x$ and $y$ as both fixed numbers, functions and dummy variables just one sentence ago.

For example when we write stupid things like $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} = \frac{df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx}$ what are abbreviating $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} = \frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)} \frac{dg(x)}{dx}$ which is again another abuse that stands for: Take the function $f$, take it's derivative $f^\prime$, take the function $g$, take it's derivative $g^\prime$, now compose $f^\prime \circ g$ and form a function which is the product of the two, that's the map
$x \mapsto (f^\prime \circ g)(x) g^\prime(x)$.

**Now knowing with all that let's tackle your case.**

By the nonsense $\frac{\partial g(t, a(t), b(t))}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial g}{ \partial t} + \frac{\partial g}{ \partial a} \frac{da}{dt} +\frac{\partial g}{ \partial b} \frac{db}{dt}$ and more specially the last term $\frac{\partial g}{ \partial b} \frac{db}{dt}$ that bothers you, we mean the following.
By $\frac{\partial g}{ \partial b}$ we mean take the function $g$, form it's partial derivative with respect to the third component (the number of the argument is the only thing that you need in order to take the partial derivative all the $x$'s and $t$'s are just abused dummies) namely $\partial_3 g$, now superpose that with the function $b$, hence $(x_0, x_1, x_2) \mapsto (\partial_3 g) (x_0, x_1, b(x_2))$.

What's $\partial_3 g$ ? Well in our abusive notation it's just 
$$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \mapsto \frac{\partial g(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}{\partial \gamma} =   \frac{d}{d\gamma} \int_\beta^\gamma f(t, \alpha) dt$$
You should recognize this as just the normal fundamental theorem of calculus. $\gamma$ is just a bound variable it doesn't "depend" on the bound dummy variable of integration, it doesn't depend on $\alpha$ or anything else.
I've used $\alpha$ $\beta$ and $\gamma$ because they are dummies and I can use whatever I want. We could've used the more familiar
$$(t,a,x) \mapsto \frac{\partial g(t,a,x)}{\partial x} =   \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(y, t) dy = f(x,t)$$

So now we need to compose our map with the function $b$, and so we get that the map

$$(t,a,x) \mapsto f(b(x), t)$$

If you evaluate this at $(t,t,t)$ ( now $t$ is free here) it would be $f(b(t),t)$. The important thing is to recognize that these variables are bound (if you've not evaluated the function at some point) and have no meaning on their own.

So yes this is the standard fundamental theorem of calculus there's no trickery involved it's just that the notation is ambiguous and confusing.

Also while it's extremely tedious you can also use the more general abstract notation for the chain rule $D_{\mathbf{a}}(f \circ g) = D_{g(\mathbf{a})}f \circ D_{\mathbf{a}}g $, and avoid any abuse of bound variables by introducing new functions all the time when it's appropriate, forming compositions $\circ$ and using the $\mapsto$ notation which will avoid all ambiguity.
But like I said since this is really tedious for doing actual computations on concrete functions, the non-abusive notation is never used outside of very theoretically oriented texts.

I also think that it's useful to read this 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_variable .

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've read through your entire post, and I'm going through it again carefully to ensure that I understand what you're saying. After reading your post and the Wikipedia article, my first question is: which of the variables in $x=x(y)$, $y=y(x)$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ are supposed to be bound variables and which are supposed to be free variables? It seems to me that, in this case, both $x$ and $y$ would be bound variables, since, If I'm not mistaken, we have, by your notation, [...]

Comment: $x \mapsto x(y)$, $y \mapsto y(x)$, and I don't it's possible to infer what the last one is supposed to be without more information?

Comment: That part I was illustrating the worst possible abuse. Strictly speaking expression such as $x = x(y)$, makes no sense. On one hand side of the equality you have the function $x$ and on the other the function $x$ evaluated at the point $y$. What's usually meant by $x = x(y)$ is $y \mapsto x(y)$, or like people say "$x$ is a function of $y$", here y is just bound variable and $x$ is a function symbol. This is common abuse of notation in calculus and physics texts. The last expression as you noted depends on the context. Here both $x$ and $y$ are free so this nonsense without context.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've gone through your post, and I think I understand everything else. Thank you for the clarification, this was quite enlightening. After years of studying mathematics (still a student, though), I wasn't even cognisant of this abuse until you explained it.