# Where is my mistake in Multivariable Chainrule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $f(t, dummyVar)=t$ and $t=x+y$, now we want to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

here are two solutions which yield two different answers, why?
First solution:
from the equation, it is obvious that:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 1$

from the chain rule we could write below equation:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}*\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}*\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$

and we know that: $f(x,y)=x+y$

so:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 2$

I am now so confused. where is my mistake?

here is the visualization:

[image]

Comment: First, you can only take $\frac{df}{dt}$.

Comment: @Randall why? you can suppose $f$ is a function of one other dummy variable so you can calculate partial derivative. $f(t,dummy var)=t$

Comment: Your confusion comes from the notation. Look at this answer that I gave to different question but I think the first part is very relevant to this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2837167/402271 .

Comment: That's not how you presented $f$.

Comment: The calculation you did would make sense _if_ you had $f=f(x,y)=f(x(t),y(t))$. But here saying $t=x+y$ does _not_ make $x$ a function of $t$; there's no such thing as $\partial x/\partial t$. If you say $f=f(t)$ where $t=x+y$ then you'd use the chain rule for $\partial f/\partial x$, as in $\partial f/\partial x=\partial f/\partial t \partial t/\partial x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that $f$ is a function of the variable $t$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not really make sense, and similarly for $y$.

In much the same manner, how does $x$ depend on $t$, in order for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ to make sense?

---

The chain rule speaks about the composition of functions.
There are two functions in your question: $f$, which depends on $t$, and an unnamed function which I'll call $g$, given by $g(x,y) = x+y$.

The function $f$ depends only on $t$ so $\frac{df}{dt}$ can be determined via usual single-variable calculus methods.
Conversely, if you consider $h:=f\circ g$, now we have a function that depends on $x$ and $y$.
We may apply the chain rule to calculate $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$, but $\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = 0$ because $h$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: You can think that two variables x and y create t and t create f so, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ does have meaning.

Comment: I find it instructive when thinking about derivative not to think in terms of variables. A function does not have ' variables', it has arguments (which lie in the function's domain). When we write $\partial f/\partial x$ for some function $f(x,y,z)$, the symbol $\partial f/\partial x$ **means** derivative with respect to the **first argument** of $f$, not to some 'variable' $x$ which you may define in terms of others.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point, but I think while this is instructive intuition the old one must work also :)

Comment: What old one? Your problem reveals some misunderstanding of the chain rule, because when you ask for $\partial f/\partial t$ where $f(t, \text{whatever})$, this just means you differentiate with respect to the first argument of $f$ (and this is fundamentally a single variable calculus problem). There is no composition of functions involved here, so there is no chain rule involved here.